# How to choose a specific column based on several clauses from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset with values of a variable at different time points. I am sharing a portion of the data below.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, TIME1 = c(1, 1, 2), VALUE1 = c(0.4, 
1.4, 0.9), TIME2 = c(3, 4, 3), VALUE2 = c(0.02, 0.12, 0.13), 
    TIME3 = c(5, 8, 7), VALUE3 = c(0.1, 0.93, 0.1), RiskGroup = c("Low", 
    "High", "Medium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2.", 
"3.", "4."))
```

I want to create a data frame which contains the value column with lowest value among all the value columns and in addition to that the corresponding TIME column and the Risk Group column. So what I want is

```
1. ID Risk Group TIME VALUE
 2. 1   Low       3.0  0.02
 3. 2   High      4.0  0.12
 4. 3  Medium     7.0. 0.13
```

I would really appreciate codes to extract this from my dataset. Thanks in advance.

My data:
[image]

Comment: I have edited my question...any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and do a group by `slice_min`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = TIME1:VALUE3, 
      names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
           names_sep="(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(ID, RiskGroup) %>%
    slice_min(VALUE) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     ID RiskGroup grp    TIME VALUE
#  <int> <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 Low       2         3  0.02
#2     2 High      2         4  0.12
#3     3 Medium    3         7  0.1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, TIME1 = c(1, 1, 2), VALUE1 = c(0.4, 
1.4, 0.9), TIME2 = c(3, 4, 3), VALUE2 = c(0.02, 0.12, 0.13), 
    TIME3 = c(5, 8, 7), VALUE3 = c(0.1, 0.93, 0.1), RiskGroup = c("Low", 
    "High", "Medium")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2.", 
"3.", "4."))
```

Comment: @akrun...some of the rows have NA...and the code is not working in presence of NA values...please guide me...I am sorry for my naive queries...

Comment: @Biostats, use `values_drop_na = TRUE` in `pivot_longer` to remove those `NA` elements

Comment: @Biostats updated the post.  Please check

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I did it and I really appreciate your help.